# function split() deprecated - besides preg_split what else needs to be changed in this code? general idea

Tags: php, split, preg-split

I know that there are several questions about this issue, but this is a particullar case... 
In the following code (in the the first and the last line)  I have to replace split with preg_split, but I think something else needs to be changed too.

Please tell me what should I change in the code for it to work, and the theory behind this change, i.e. the gereral idea behind switching between split and preg_split. The code which needs the transition is:

```
            $opt = split("_",$key);
            if($opt[0]=="id" && $val!="0" && $val!=""){

                        some queries

            $shuffle=split("_",$_POST['all_'.$i]);
```

Comment: Can you post your input and expected output?

Comment: Use `explode` instead of split.

Comment: Yes to @PoulsQ.  You are not using `preg_split`.

Comment: I have tried using preg_split instead of split, and I have got the errors "no ending delimiter '_' found on that line ..."

Comment: @KlaussGekker: You don't need `preg_split()`. **Use `explode()`.**

Comment: Thanks everybody! I have replaced split with explode and no error appears. everything is working okay. Good luck and thank you @PoulsQ !

Comment: @KlaussGekker: I downvoted the question not only because it looks like you just didn't want to read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) (*Tip: split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.*) but also because of "this is a particular case". Does that mean *your* particular case is better than the others? I would downvote again if I could.

Comment: @Jon, It is not better better, it is just different... you see, I have read other cases where explode was not apropriate to use instead of split, because it can be used with just one delimiter...  but in this particular case, explode works perfectly...  anyways... thanks for your constructive critique and I wish you good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` instead of `split`. Your code should look like this :

```
$opt = explode("_",$key);
if($opt[0]=="id" && $val!="0" && $val!=""){

   some queries

$shuffle=explode("_",$_POST['all_'.$i]);
```

Documentation : https://www.php.net/explode

Comment: I have replaced split with explode and no error appears. everything is working okay. Good luck and thank you @PoulsQ !

Answer (score 1):

PHP is in the process of dropping an older POSIX-compatible regex extension in favour of the newer PCRE extension. This means that older functions like `split()` and `ereg()` will be removed in time.

The PCRE equivalent for `split()` is `preg_split()`, which has a modified syntax. For your code you'd use:

```
$opt = preg_split("/_/",$key);
```

However, a Regex function is a heavyweight tool and isn't required here. You just need `explode()`, like this:

```
$opt = explode("_",$key);
```